# Getting Facebook posts and statuses without duplicates

Tags: facebook, status, posts

I'm trying to write a server-side application that reads posts and statuses from a business page on Facebook.  When I request `/posts`, I get many duplicate statuses, as if every edit to the status is available with a different id.  As a solution, I thought I would ignore the statuses in `/posts`, and merge in the statuses from `/statuses`.  But `/statuses` requires a user auth token, not just an app token, and it would be unacceptable to prompt the user at this point.

1. Why are the two endpoints authorized differently?  This is a publicly visible business page, why do I need a user token to read statuses, but not to read posts?
2. Is there a way to get statuses without duplicates from the /posts page?

Comment: /posts shouldn't have 'duplicates' - i'm not really sure what you mean by this

Comment: Hmm, the `type=status` posts I'm seeing might just be the tagging activity.  They have different `story_tags` data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "duplicate" statuses were in fact not.  `/posts` shows not only what you have posted to your own page, but also others' pages.  In this case, the "duplicates" were actually a status being posted to other people's timelines because they were being tagged in the status.

I didn't find an indicator in the graph api to distinguish between these statuses, except that the statuses on my own page have a `message` attribute, while those on others' pages have a `story` attribute.  It seems a pretty slight distinction, but it works.